# How do I split a string so that symbols are made into their own list item without the use of regex?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
Jamies_string = "Hello there {my name is jamie}".split()

print(Jamies_string)
```

Output here:

```
['Hello', 'there', '{my', 'name', 'is', 'jamie}']
```

Desired output here:

```
['Hello', 'there', '{', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'jamie', '}']
```

I really want to stay away from any soltutions that involve the use of the re library, thanks.

Comment: Why to you want to stay away from regular expressions?  They are definitvely overused, but sometimes they are indeed the right solution.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying out making a programming language and I want it to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: @JamieJohnson One regex split will be more efficient than most other alternatives you can think of.

Comment: it's better not to split at all in those cases, and extract the tokens one by one, without creating lists. Using regular expression is what `ply` (python lex-yacc) uses, so I guess it's pretty efficient. I myself did the splitting using replace+split, and it's clearly less efficient.

Comment: If you want to write a parser, look into [some parser library](https://github.com/webmaven/python-parsing-tools).

Comment: Any reason you have Python 2.7 _and_ Python 3.x tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to create a function that categorises characters and use that as a key function for `itertools.groupby()`:

```
WHITESPACE = 0
LETTERS = 1
DIGITS = 2
SYMBOLS = 3

def character_class(c):
    if c.isspace():
        return WHITESPACE
    if c.isalpha():
        return LETTERS
    if c.isdigit():
        return DIGITS
    return SYMBOLS

s = "Hello there {my name is jamie}"
tokens = [
    "".join(chars)
    for cls, chars in itertools.groupby(s, character_class)
    if cls != WHITESPACE
]
print(tokens)
```

prints

```
['Hello', 'there', '{', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'jamie', '}']
```

You clarified that you want to avoid regular expressions for performance reasons.  The approach in this answer is definitely slower than correctly using regular expressions.  However, I don't think your project is at a stage where you need to worry about performance.

Comment: groupby is a nice alternative to regexes, yeah.

Answer (score 4):

You could add spaces around those symbols first, then use `split()`, e.g.

```
>>> s = "Hello there {my name is jamie}"
>>> s.replace("{", " { ").replace("}", " } ").split()
['Hello', 'there', '{', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'jamie', '}']
```

Answer (score 1):

The string you're using is similar to [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) in Python. If so, you could use [`Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter) class to parse it:

```
from string import Formatter


def solve(s):
    for f in Formatter().parse(s):
        yield from f[0].split()
        if f[1]:
            yield from ['{'] + f[1].split() + ['}']
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> list(solve("Hello there {my name is jamie}"))
['Hello', 'there', '{', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'jamie', '}']

>>> list(solve("Hello there {my name is jamie} {hello world} end."))
['Hello', 'there', '{', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'jamie', '}', '{', 'hello', 'world', '}', 'end.']
```

Answer (score 1):

One way (not as clean as other answers, but it works):

```
def tokenize(string):
    WHITESPACE = 0 #Borrowed from Sven's answer
    LETTERS = 1
    DIGITS = 2
    SYMBOLS = 3
    def character_class(c):
        if c.isspace():
            return WHITESPACE
        elif c.isalpha():
            return LETTERS
        elif c.isdigit():
            return DIGITS
        return SYMBOLS

    lastType = character_class(string[0])
    chunk = ""

    for i, char in enumerate(string):
        charType = character_class(char)
        if charType == WHITESPACE:
            if chunk: #Only yield if non-empty
                yield chunk
            chunk = ""
            lastType = character_class(string[i + 1]) #Type of next character because we want the next part to not have leading whitespace
            continue #Don't add to chunk
        elif charType != lastType: #Different type
            if chunk: #Only yield if non-empty
                yield chunk
            chunk = ""
            lastType = charType
        chunk += char
    if chunk:
        yield chunk
print(list(tokenize("Hello there {my name is jamie}")))
```

Sample output:

```
['Hello', 'there', '{', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'jamie', '}']
```

This is more or less manually doing what `itertools.groupby` does.

Answer (score 1):

Make a pass through the string and put whitespace around all punctuation characters then split on white space.

```
>>>> import string
>>> s = "Hello there {my name is jamie}"
>>> s = ''.join(c if c.isalnum() or c.isspace() else ' {} '.format(c) for c in s)
>>> s.split()
['Hello', 'there', '{', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'jamie', '}']
>>>
```

---

Expanding that third line a bit --

```
a = []
for c in s:
    if not c.isalnum() and not c.isspace():
        c = ' ' + c + ' '
    a.append(c)

s = ''.join(a)
s.split()
```